# Java Iterator - how to set the first element of an iteration?

Tags: java, iterator

The problem Im having is pretty straight forward. As part of a project I have to programm an Iterator that takes variables (new Class type `Var` - not really important) and `boolean` values.
The Iterator should return all possibilities - like a truthtable. It is specifically said that the first call of `.next()` should return every variable with value false and after that every call of `.next()` sets the lexicographically largest variable to its other state and so on (as I said just like a truthtable).

I pretty much got everything handled except for that first call of `.next()`. Does anybody know how this is possible to implement?

```java
public Iterator<VarAssignment> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<VarAssignment>() {

            Map<Var, Boolean> map2 = (HashMap<Var, Boolean>) ((HashMap<Var, Boolean>) map).clone();

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                // returns false if at least one value is 'false'
                return (map2.containsValue(false));
            }

            @Override
            public VarAssignment next() {
                if (!this.hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();

                VarAssignment varAssignment = new VarAssignment();
                varAssignment.map = map2;
                List<Var> lex = varAssignment.getVars();

                // correcting map2
                for (int i = lex.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    map2.put(lex.get(i), !map2.get(lex.get(i)));
                    if (map2.get(lex.get(i))) break;
                }
                // setting map2 to newAssignment.map
                varAssignment.map = map2;
                // returning newAssignment
                return varAssignment;
            }
        };
    }
```

```java
public List<Var> getVars() {
        // Sorting the keys of the map by name.
        List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Var var : map.keySet()) {
            sorted.add(var.getName());
        }
        Collections.sort(sorted);

        // Creating a list of Var objects from the sorted list of strings.
        List<Var> out = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String name : sorted) {
            out.add(new Var(name));
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: You can write your custom iterator for the class by implementing "Iterator"  and overriding next().

Comment: yes, that is what I did (code in edited question) but I cant find a solution to specifically advise the first call.

Comment: Comment in the `hasNext()` is incorrect. This method will return `true` if there's at least one value of `false` in the map.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko yes both are seperate classes, the `Var` class handles what a variable is and the `VarAssignment` class is the class in which this iterator is implementet in (methode called `iterator()`). A `VarAssignment` contains a Map `Map<Var, Boolean>` that gives each variable a boolean Value which the `.next()` can than return.

Comment: Add the code from classes `VarAssignment` and `Var` to the question (only those portions that are relevant to the question, so that their structure will clear to the reader of the question).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko the rest of the code is useless for this specific problem. If you know anything about my issue (even if its generic as fuck) please tell me

Comment: You didn't understand me. The structure of your classes should be clear without reading through the comments. And I still have no clue why do you need to create a new instance of `VarAssignment` and where `lex` list comes from.

Comment: BTW, avoid assigning properties like this `varAssignment.map = map2;`. In Java it's bad practice, in this case you can provide the map through the constructor. And the map should be encapsulated within the class.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko the `lex` List comes from the `.getVars()` method which returns all variables sorted by name from the lexicographically smallest to the Lexicographically largest. Basically all the comments are just there so I can remember exactly what everything does when I read through the code in a few weeks.

And what other way would there be to initialies a `VarAssignment` object within the Iterator?

Comment: `lex List comes from the .getVars()` - that's obvious. `all variables sorted by name from the lexicographically` and that is not obvious. And again it's not clear where this list comes from. It's the `keySet` of the `HashMap` dumped into a `List`? Why do you assume that it's sorted? Your question still lucks details.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I've updated the Question with the code for the `.getVars()`. But as I said this has nothing to do with the Question in general.

Comment: So you want to iterate over the *keys* of a `HashMap` in sorted order, right? The question is why iterator is of type `VarAssignment` (and consequently `next()` returns `VarAssignment`), not `String` (the type of keys in the map) ?

Comment: Another question: why `hasNext()` designed to return the same value? Because the result returned by `map2.containsValue(false)` would stay the same unless you're going to mutate the map (which isn't observed in the code).